# Php Create Zip on Fly and download

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zip

I am creating an application where users can upload as many documents. I am using ASW S3 for file storage. Each file is private and not accessible publicly.

I want to provide download bulk feature to the users. For this I have 2 approach:
 1. Download all required files on local server from S3, zip it and then upload the zip on S3, so that once the zip is uploaded it can be downloaded from anywhere without hampering my local server storage. This is pretty straight forward and doable. But the problem is the user would need to wait till this zip is created and available for download.
 2. Create the zip on fly, add the files on the fly and start the download instantly on the user end. I really want to implement this solution, but even after searching since last 2 days, I wouldn't get the right solution.

Any guidance and help on this would be appreciable.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/

Comment: #kainaw I had already know about this library. As I want to add the file one by one and also send the stream back to client at the same time, this library wont be useful. I need something very similar to what dropbox does. Thank You :)

Comment: @kainaw I used your suggestion and it seems its working now. The only problem is that the download doesn't shows in the download tab unless it is fully downloaded to memory and then in a second everything is download.

Comment: I would expect it to show up in the downloadING list, but now in the downloadED until it is complete. The reason is that you aren't telling the client the total file length (you can't know it). So, it is treated as a data stream of unknown length. When it ends, it is suddenly changed to a downloaded file, not a stream.